# ImportError: No module named 'xlsxwriter' python34

Tags: python, python-import, xlsxwriter

I am using python34 on windows and trying to create an excell file. I figured out that xlrd and xlwt is supported by only for 2.6 and 2.7 versions. Then I downloaded/installed xlsxwriter via pip and command prompt. Both pip and xlsxwriter module were installed succesfully w/o error on command prompt. The module is seen in my my C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\XlsxWriter-0.7.3-py3.4.egg. Is that .egg file how the file type is supposed to be? I keep getting the same error saying that No module named 'xlsxwriter' with my simple sample program. Although I found that the question '[ImportError: No module named xlsxwriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27385097/importerror-no-module-named-xlsxwriter)' informative, that does not help much to me. Could you have any comment or suggestion? Thanks so much!

Comment: Both `xlrd` and `xlwt` are supported on Python 3.3+.  http://www.python-excel.org

Comment: Use `pip` to install packages,like so: `pip install xlrd`. You can do this in command prompt or PowerShell

Comment: The `.egg` file means its installed correctly; but you have a very old version - try `pip install --upgrade xlsxwriter`

Comment: Thank you very much Burhan Khalid!! That worked..:) I was suffering for days..

Comment: Nicarus, thank you for your suggestion. my xlrd module was compiled too with pip install xlrd on command prompt !