# 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'add_chart'

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm gettin this **error**:

```
AttributeError: 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'add_chart'
```

While running this **code** (python version 3.7.4):

```
import re
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile
import numpy

# ... other code here not involved to this part ...

df = pd.DataFrame({"city": city_list, "tourist": tourist_list, "month": month_list})
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('C:\\Users\\portovenere\\Downloads\\exc.xlsx')
workbook = writer.book

chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'column'})

chart.add_series({
    'totals':     '=Sheet1!$A$3:$A$21',
    'gap':        2,
})
```

`add_chart` usage is explained in this [pandas xlsx-writer documentation](https://pandas-xlsxwriter-charts.readthedocs.io/chart_column.html#chart-column) that I'm following.

I see `add_chart` is defined in [XlsxWriter/workbook.py](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/blob/master/xlsxwriter/workbook.py) at line 228

```
def add_chart(self, options):
        """
        Create a chart object.
        Args:
            options: The chart type and subtype options.
        Returns:
            Reference to a Chart object.
        """
```

What I'm missing?

Thank you

Comment: Well, obviously "workbook" has no attribute "add_chart", did you try to use `dir` on `workbook` to see what's in there?

Comment: You probably need to set `xlsxwriter` as the `engine` for ExcelWriter. It is probably using openpyxl instead. Refer to the example you linked to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding this line

```
import xlsxwriter
```

as suggested in [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27385097/importerror-no-module-named-xlsxwriter), and specifying `xlsxwriter` as suggested  in the comment, solved the issue.

Thank you again