# Installed xlsxwriter but python says theres no module?

Tags: python, command-line, xlsxwriter

I am working with xlsxwriter but every-time i try to run my file i get the following error:

```
No module named 'xlsxwriter'
```

i have tried pip installing it but when i do that i get the following message:

```
Requirement already satisfied: xlsxwriter
```

does anyone know what causes this? I have also tried seeing what version is installed and it is up to date too.
(I am running these in command line in the folder which contains my python scripts)

Comment: Can you show the code snip you've tried?  Silly question, but did you begin with `import xlsxwriter` ?

Comment: @Plato77 the code would be too long to post but thats the line im getting the error on

Comment: have you tried using a virtual environment?  Alternatively might need to uninstall all packages and then reinstall

Comment: there are some ideas to try here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27385097/importerror-no-module-named-xlsxwriter

Comment: ive tried uninstalling and reinstalling again and it hasnt, worked ill have to see if a virtual environment works

Comment: You're probably running the program with a different Python installation than the one you're installing the module for. You should use virtual environments. Also, please provide the entire error message.