# No module named 'xlsxwriter' after installing module into virtual environment

Tags: python, pandas, virtualenv, xlsxwriter

1) i created virtual environment in the same folder where my .py located

2) I activated virtual environment

3) I installed "xlsxwriter" into my newly created virtual environment. I can see 
it.

[image]

4) Executing script, I got an error: No module named 'xlsxwriter'

```
    import xlsxwriter
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlsxwriter'
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: What OS? How do you run the script? To what python does the shebang line point?

Comment: Windows 10 Enterprise. Virtual environment. 64-bit OS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named xlsxwriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27385097/importerror-no-module-named-xlsxwriter)

Comment: Thank you Michael, I used tarball. But what was all that executions happened? What is tarball?